# Уравнение окружности в пространстве

Tags: математика, геометрия

Есть задача вывести уравнение (найти несколько точек) окружности по точке центра и нормали плоскости окружности. Я убрал точку центра и принял её (0,0,0) для простоты (потом просто прибавлю к результатам координаты моего центра).

В чем проблема. 
Уравнение сферы x²+y²+z²=R²
Уравнение плоскости Ax+By+Cz=0, где N(A,B,C) - вектор нормаль.

Мое уравнение - это система последних двух уравнений.

Далее у меня затык... Мне нужно найти серию точек по окружности по часовой стрелке через шаг α=360°/N.

Я так понял, то данное уравнение мне необходимо не просто решить а еще и привести к сферическим координатам. Но как? Математику знаю нормально но тут явно затупил.

**UPD:** Есть еще некий вариант решения, зная (X,Y) нужных точек окружности на плоскости, получить (X,Y,Z) путём "вращения" осей взаимозависимости от  N(A,B,C) но как это реализовать вопрос..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пошли довольно сложным путем. Все делается проще.

Для начала, надо построить ортонормированную систему координат в плоскости окружности. Для этого надо найти любой вектор, перпендикулярный вектору нормали. Это - самая "некрасивая" часть решения. И в этом месте надо не бояться ставить условные операторы - согласно "теореме о причесывании ежа" из топологии, без них не обойтись.

Самый простой способ повернуть вектор на прямой угол - векторно умножить его на что-нибудь. Но если перемножаемые вектора будут близки по направлению - пострадает точность (а если они коллинеарны - будет ноль).

Поэтому предлагаю рассмотреть три базисных вектора (**i**, **j** и **k**) и умножить на тот, который "самый непохожий". Для этого *найдем координату с наименьшим модулем*. Пусть, для определенности, |A| < |B| и |C|. Значит, умножаем на вектор **i** и получаем первый из векторов базиса местной системы координат:

**i<sub>1</sub>** = **n** x **i** = (A**i** + B**j** + C**k**) x **i** = -B**k** + C**j**

Теперь снова умножим его на вектор нормали и получим второй вектор базиса:

**j<sub>1</sub>** = **n** x **i<sub>1</sub>** = (A**i** + B**j** + C**k**) x (-B**k** + C**j**) = (раскройте скобки сами)

Теперь осталось нормировать базисные вектора, чтобы они стали единичными - и можно воспользоваться параметрическим уравнением окружности:

**r** = **r<sub>0</sub>** + R cos φ **i<sub>1</sub>** / |i<sub>1</sub>| + R sin φ **j<sub>1</sub>** / |j<sub>1</sub>|

Comment: О! точно, можно же перпендикуляры использовать! Как я не догадался. А точность мне не нужна, достаточно вычислить примерно значения точек окружности. Будем проверять. Спасибо.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик нельзя забывать о точности. При делении на околонулевое число точность падает так, что будет заметно невооруженным глазом.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик главное правило вычислительной математики - избегать сингулярностей.

Comment: я так понимаю параметрическое уравнение окружности это её проекция на плоскость базиса? а третью координату мы высчитываем из уравнения плоскости?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик это векторное уравнение. Оно в любых координатах работает.

Comment: Да, получилось. Все отлично. Спасибо